# getStringExtra() returns null when starting activity from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

**SOLVED**

When trying to start AppCompatActivity from my BroadcastReceiver, passed extra parameter readed in onCreate() is null.Where can be problem?

(Android 5.1.1)

In BroadcastReceiver I'm calling my activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    . . .
    Intent detailsActivityIntent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DetailsActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_ID, accountId);
    detailsActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(detailsActivityIntent);
}
```

BroadcastReceiver is opened from notification like this:

```
. . .
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(
            NotificationActionReceiver.getPendingIntent(account, getApplicationContext()));
. . .

public PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Account account, Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActionReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(DetailsActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_ID, account.getAccountId());

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, account.getId().intValue(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

In my onCreate I'm just opening fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    String accountId = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_ACCOUNT_ID);
    // ** accountId is null **

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.details_container, DetailsFragment.newInstance(accountId))
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the LogCat error?

Comment: There is no error related to that behavior, just NPE caused later due to null parameter.

Comment: What's the null parameter?

Comment: In that Activity's onCreate I'm accessing passed parameter like String accountId = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_ACCOUNT_ID); and because onCreate is not called, accountId is null.

Comment: edit: onCreate method added

Comment: Maybe your activity isn't destroyed completly... try to put this line in your onResume

Comment: OK, so I've been playing a little bit with that and it looks like onCreate is called, but getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_ACCOUNT_ID) returns null. Question updated...

Comment: Why you don't use getIntent().getStringExtra(DetailsActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_ID)? you sure that `DetailsActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_ID` is a String?

Comment: It is the same parameter - it's called inside DetailsActivity.

Comment: So with DetailsActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_ID didnt' work?

Comment: It's solved now, I'm blind - see the answer, it was really stupid! Thanks for your time, Skizo!!

Comment: Woops, looks like I'm tired too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent detailsActivityIntent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DetailsActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_ID, accountId);
detailsActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(detailsActivityIntent);
```

I do not know if you have messed while posting the code or this is it's actual state but you are setting Extra on **intent** instance but you are starting activity from **detailsActivityIntent**  instance.